# creating and intersecting hexahedrons with CGAL

Tags: python, geometry, cgal

Using the [Python bindings](http://cgal-python.gforge.inria.fr/) for [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/), I can't work out how create a hexahedron, nor how to calculate its intersection with another hexahedron.

I have 8 input points, which are the corners of the hexahedron:

[image: a hexahedron - a shape with six faces, eight corners]

My code does this:

```
P = Polyhedron_3()
bottom = P.make_tetrahedron(p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3])
top = P.make_tetrahedron(p[4],p[5],p[6],p[7])
left = P.make_tetrahedron(p[0],p[1],p[5],p[4])
right = P.make_tetrahedron(p[3],p[2],p[6],p[7])
front = P.make_tetrahedron(p[4],p[7],p[3],p[0])
back = P.make_tetrahedron(p[1],p[2],p[6],p[5])
```

but when I count the points in the resulting polyhedron there are 24 - each face is unjoined with its neighbours.

How can I build a solid hexahedron using Python CGAL?

And, finally, having successfully constructed two such polyhedron, how do I calculate their intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to create an initial tetrahedron, then use `split_edge` three times and moving the newly created vertices to where they are supposed to be.  Then use another combination of `split_facet` and `split_edge` to "mold" the hexahedron into place.

See [Section 25.3.7 of **CGAL Documentation**](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Polyhedron/Chapter_main.html) to see this being done in explicit detail for a special case hexahedron with vertices `[0,0,0]`,`[1,0,0]`,`[0,1,0]`,`[0,0,1]`,`[1,1,0]`,`[1,0,1]`,`[0,1,1]`, and `[1,1,1]`, without (I believe) any loss of generality.